# Does Germany has a Tax law similar to Like-kind exchange ( section 1031 of IRS in US)?

Tags: real-estate, capital-gains-tax, germany, taxable-benefits, like-kind-exchange

I am 24 year old software developer living in Germany. I am an expat here and I am about to receive my permanent residence (Niederlassungserlaubnis) in a year. I am very interested in investments mainly in real-estate. I was wondering whether there are any tax laws in Germany that are similar to like-kind exchange laws in the US irrespective of whether they are targeted at the individuals or Corporate holdings. Thank you.

Comment: If you intend to make money by flipping houses, then you should be aware of the *Grunderwerbssteuer* (real estate purchase tax) you need to pay whenever you buy real estate in Germany. It's between 3.5% and 6.5% of the sale price, depending on location. This tax greatly limits the profit margin of house flippers.

Comment: But how does one define a house flipper ? is that based on holding period of the asset ?

Comment: "house flipper" is not a legal term. It's a term for someone who (attempts to) make money by buying real estate just to sell it again later at a higher price. The *Grunderwerbssteuer* needs to be paid whenever someone pays money to acquire a property (unless it's from a close family member). There is no minimum time for it. It doesn't matter if you owned a property for 10 days or for 10 years.

Comment: ah , so if i got it right, no matter who is acquiring the property, the acquirer has to buy a grunderwerbssteuer to the government. Is it something like mehrwertsteuer that is generally added when someone buys something ? is grunderwerbssteuer a realestate version of mehrwertsteuer ?

Comment: The difference is that as a reseller you only pay *Mehrwertsteuer* on your profits. When you resell something to a customer, you get the *Mehrwertsteuer* you paid to your supplier back. But the *Grunderwerbssteuer* does not work that way. When you buy a property, you pay it in full. When you sell it again, the buyer has to pay the full tax again.

Comment: okay and sorry to ask so many questions, if i understood right, 
I have to pay grunderwerbsteuer while buying the property and while selling it, I have to pay mehrwertsteuer. So while selling the mehrwertsteuer, is that the capital gains tax which is 25% flat ? os is capital gains tax of 25% separate from mehrwertsteuer ?

Comment: Real estate deals are exempt from *Mehrwertsteuer* (sales tax). But the profits from real estate trading are sometimes applicable for *Einkommenssteuer* (Income tax). See the answer by amon for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under limited circumstances. Per [§6b EstG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/estg/__6b.html) you don't have to tax the profits from the sale (Veräußerung) of a business asset, if:

- the sold asset is land or a building or certain other assets
- you held the sold asset for the last 6 years
- you acquire an asset of the same type within 4–6 years (depends on the asset type)
- and possibly other conditions

More precisely, the replacement costs can be used as a tax exemption that you can apply in advance to the profits of a sale.

This is not useful as a tax loophole and has more to do with the concept of stille Reserven (hidden assets), which are assets that don't appear on the balance sheet. The value increase of real estate is a typical hidden asset under German accounting practices (which are quite unlike GAAP).

This stuff can get complicated, so definitely get an accountant to assist you.

Comment: Thanks, thats quite an useful piece of information you gave. I have also read that one does not need to pay tax on the profits of the sale of a house in which the Op has lived for more that 10 years. Not sure how correct this information is though.

When you said acquiring an asset of same type within 4 to 6 years , does that mean one can withhold the tax upto next 4-6 years after the sale of an asset in hope of acquiring a new one of similar type ?

Comment: You're thinking of the Privates Veräußerungsgeschäft per [§23 EstG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/estg/__23.html). It applies to private assets, not to business assets – those two are logically separate under German tax laws, even if you're acting as sole proprietor (Einzelunternehmer). Sales of private real estate does not generate taxable income if (1) the asset was held >10 years or (2) you lived in there for a certain time (~3 years are sufficient). See also: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/wissen/verkaufen/wann-ist-der-immobilienverkauf-steuerfrei.html

Comment: Re §6b yes you withhold the tax in advance but have to repay with interest if you don't have enough qualifying expenses. This case is explicitly discussed in the EstG. The interest rate should be specified in the Abgabenordnung (AO), IIRC it's Basiszinssatz + 1% so fairly cheap. Beyond interest there are no penalties here.

Comment: Thank you, that is clear.